# Breakpoint errors in javaeclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, list, sorting

Good evening everyone. I'm working on a piece of homework and I finally have it nearly complete. Currently, the only thing stopping compilation is a breakpoint error at line 42. Eclipse tells me that it is the variable "list" being uninitialized, however, i cant find where or why this is happening.

The program is for a homework assignment in beginning java. It is designed to import a list of names from a text file called names.txt, then be able to sort through them in an interface, and while the menu is yet to be added, I want to get compiled and make sure its working before I go changing things again.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Name {

   private String givenName;
   private int[]  ranks = new int[11];

   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      List<Name> list = new ArrayList<Name>();

      loadFile();

      System.out.println( list.get( 0 ).getPop( 0 ) );
   }

   private static void loadFile() {
      Scanner inputStream = null;
      String fileName = "names.txt";

      try {
         inputStream = new Scanner( new File( fileName ) );
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println( "Error opening file named: " + fileName );
         System.out.println( "Exiting..." );
      }

      while ( inputStream.hasNextLine() ) {
         String line = inputStream.nextLine();
         String[] tokens = new String[0];
         String givenName = tokens[0];

         int[] numList = new int[tokens.length - 1];

         for ( int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++ ) {
            numList[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt( tokens[i].trim() );
         }

         list.add( new Name( givenName, numList ) );
      }
   }

   // here we get the name for the
   public Name(String name, int[] popularityRanks) {
      givenName = name;

      for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) {
         ranks[i] = popularityRanks[i];
      }
   }

   public String getName() {
      return givenName;
   }

   public int getPop( int decade ) {
      if ( decade >= 1 && decade <= 11 ) {
         return ranks[decade];
      }
      else {
         return -1;
      }
   }

   public String getHistoLine( int decade ) {
      String histoLine = ranks[decade] + ": ";

      return histoLine;
   }

   public String getHistogram() {
      String histogram = "";

      for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) {
         histogram += ranks[i] + ": " + this.getHistoLine( i ) + "\n";
      }

      return histogram;
   }
}
```

In addition, I used lists to configure the variables, but now i am deeply regretting it as I feel far more comfortable with just multi-dimensional arrays. As this is homework related, I completely understand if no one wants to help me fix this second part and give me some code to change the lists to arrays.

I'm burnt out and just want it to compile at this point. Any pointers on where to go from here?

Comment: I can add names.txt if it would help, but I think it is useless for this question

Comment: Can you add the error message and a snippet of the names.txt. Right off I can see the code is poorly organized.

Comment: Names.txt is a list of names with 11 integer for their possible ranks.

A 83 140 228 286 426 612 486 577 836 0 0
Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215
Aaron 193 208 218 274 279 232 132 36 32 31 41
Abagail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 958
Abbey 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 451 428

Comment: The error given was *********************************************************************

Multiple markers at this line
 - list cannot be resolved
 - Line breakpoint:Name [line: 41] - 
  loadFile()

Comment: @JWelch the txt file is not required. Its an out-of-scope error. I hope my answered fixed you r problem.

Comment: @AniMenon ok, so by out of scope you mean that the variable is unable to access other sections / be accessed by other sections? Could yo clarify a little more please?

Comment: Your list is not visible to the point your are going to add a Name object. Its better to pass the list as a reference to the loadFile() method, As like follows

Comment: @JWelch yes. Check the answer below. You had declared "list" in the main(), hence making it local to main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list declaration/initialization is in the main and you are trying to access it from loadFile method.

Just move you `List<Name> list = new ArrayList<Name>();` as a class variable(put it right above the main) and your code should compile.

Eg:

```
public class Name {

   private String givenName;
   private int[]  ranks = new int[11];
   static List<Name> list = new ArrayList<Name>();

   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      loadFile();
   ......
```

Comment: That caused another more in a different section. Both areas are now referencing that they are unable to make static references to a non-static variable, as well as the same line reporting a breakpoint error...

Comment: You are a scholar and a saint. Solved. Thank you

Comment: @JWelch You will get used to such errors. And there are many ways to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not visible to the point your are going to add a `Name` object. Its better to pass the `list` as a reference to the `loadFile()` method, As like follows

```
loadFile(list); // Method call from the main().
```

And Load file

```
private static void loadFile(List list) {
  // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've restructured your code fixing the scopes and the object definition. If your individual logic is correct(which I haven't really checked), you should get your desired output).

What you seem to have mixed up is the object and the calling client. The Name private class is a private object which is being instantiated in the main method. Subsequently the public methods of the Name object is being called upon.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    private static class Name{

        private final int items = 11;
        private String givenName;
        private int[] ranks;


        //Constructor
        public Name(String name, int[] popularityRanks) {
            givenName = name;
            ranks = new int[items];

            for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
                ranks[i] = popularityRanks[i];
            }
        }

        public String getName() {
            return givenName;
        }

        public int getPop(int decade) {
            if (decade >= 1 && decade <= items) {
                return ranks[decade];
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public String getHistoLine(int decade) {
            String histoLine = ranks[decade] + ": ";

            return histoLine;
        }

        public String getHistogram() {
            String histogram = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                histogram += ranks[i] + ": " + this.getHistoLine(i) + "\n";
            }

            return histogram;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Name> list = loadFile();

        System.out.println(list.get(0).getPop(0));
    }


    private static List<Name> loadFile() {
        List<Name> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        String fileName = "names.txt";

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file named: " + fileName);
            System.out.println("Exiting...");
        }

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = new String[0];
            String givenName = tokens[0];

            int[] numList = new int[tokens.length - 1];

            for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                numList[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
            }

            list.add(new Name(givenName, numList));
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It worries me that my structure is so bad that someone went out of their way to fix it...

Comment: The thing with SO is that you don't need to thank anyone, just accept the answer that best addresses your requirement and up vote the ones that came close. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ill advise you declare your list outside main, 
Second, you want to populate the list before calling getPop. 
look where you have:

System.out.println(list.get(0).getPop(0));

At this point list.get(0) returns null since the list hasn't been populated yet...and from your code getPop(0) will return -1, so the line above basically doesn't mean anything at that point.

And as for converting the list to arrays to make it "multidimensional"....
First lists can also be "multidimensional", if u know how to declare them...e.g

List> list = new ArrayList();

is a 2d array list.
Second generic lists like the one above are way flexible and have huge advantages over arrays, for example they can be dynamically modified; you can change their size at runtime unlike arrays.

With that said, if you want to convert a list to an array you need the type of the list and it's size and then it's easy using the toArray() method...like this:

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);